# Can I define Resources as part of a Style?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code currently looks like this:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource HG}" >
   <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Label">
         <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource HelpTextColor}" />
         <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource HD}" />
      </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

and I have this used in a Grid like this:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource HG}" >
   <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Label">
         <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource HelpTextColor}" />
         <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource HD}" />
      </Style>
   </Grid.Resources>
```

Is there any way that I can combine the Grid.Resources into the Style I called `HG` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Style` has a `TargetType` property, which is used to determine the target control type.
 `HG` style `TagetType` is `Grid` where the second style `TargetType` is a `Label`. Merging these 2 does not make sense.

It might be possible using [CSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/) but I never tried that.